# At what point is the page's title get default initial value in ASP .NET with Orchard CMS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, orchardcms

I downloaded a complete ASP. NET MVC application, but when I try to change the title of the page in the Razor view, I get the **Default value + MyNewTitle**.

I tried to change the page's title in the following:

```
Layout.Title = "_test";
Model.Title = "_test";
```

But I got: **SiteName - _test**

This is the beginning of Layout.cshtml

```
@functions {
    // To support the layout classifaction below. Implementing as a razor function because we can, could otherwise be a Func<string[], string, string> in the code block following.

    string CalcuClassify(string[] zoneNames, string classNamePrefix)
    {
        var zoneCounter = 0;
        var zoneNumsFilled = string.Join("", zoneNames.Select(zoneName => { ++zoneCounter; return Model[zoneName] != null ? zoneCounter.ToString() : ""; }).ToArray());
        return HasText(zoneNumsFilled) ? classNamePrefix + zoneNumsFilled : "";
    }
}
    @{
    //Layout.Title = "test";
    //Model.Title = "TEST";

    /* Global includes for the theme
    ***************************************************************/
    Script.Require("jQuery").AtHead();
    Style.Include("site.css");
    Style.Include("styles.css");
    Script.Require("jQuery");
    Script.Include("scripts.js");

    RegisterLink(new Orchard.UI.Resources.LinkEntry
    {
        Rel = "stylesheet",
        Type = "text/css",
        Href = "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700,300italic,400italic,500italic,700italic&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,latin-ext,cyrillic"
    });

    RegisterLink(new Orchard.UI.Resources.LinkEntry
    {
        Rel = "stylesheet",
        Type = "text/css",
        Href = "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese,latin-ext,cyrillic"
    });

    /* Some useful shortcuts or settings
    ***************************************************************/

    Func<dynamic, dynamic> Zone = x => Display(x); // Zone as an alias for Display to help make it obvious when we're displaying zones

    /* Layout classification based on filled zones
    ***************************************************************/

    //Add classes to the wrapper div to toggle aside widget zones on and off
    var asideClass = CalcuClassify(new[] { "AsideFirst", "AsideSecond" }, "aside-"); // for aside-1, aside-2 or aside-12 if any of the aside zones are filled
    if (HasText(asideClass))
    {
        Model.Classes.Add(asideClass);
    }

    //Add classes to the wrapper div to toggle tripel widget zones on and off
    var tripelClass = CalcuClassify(new[] { "TripelFirst", "TripelSecond", "TripelThird" }, "tripel-"); // for tripel-1, triple-2, etc. if any of the tripel zones are filled
    if (HasText(tripelClass))
    {
        Model.Classes.Add(tripelClass);
    }

    //Add classes to the wrapper div to toggle quad widget zones on and off
    var footerQuadClass = CalcuClassify(new[] { "FooterQuadFirst", "FooterQuadSecond", "FooterQuadThird", "FooterQuadFourth" }, "split-"); // for quad-1, quad-2, etc. if any of the quad zones are filled
    if (HasText(footerQuadClass))
    {
        Model.Classes.Add(footerQuadClass);
    }

    /* Inserting some ad hoc shapes
    ***************************************************************/

    WorkContext.Layout.Header.Add(New.Branding(), "5"); // Site name and link to the home page
    WorkContext.Layout.Footer.Add(New.BadgeOfHonor(), "5"); // Powered by Orchard
    //WorkContext.Layout.Footer.Add(New.User(), "10"); // Login and dashboard links

    /* Last bit of code to prep the layout wrapper
    ***************************************************************/

    Model.Id = "layout-wrapper";
    var tag = Tag(Model, "div"); // using Tag so the layout div gets the classes, id and other attributes added to the Model
}
@tag.StartElement
```

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess from the code shown and assume you're using [Orchard CMS](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard)?

Comment: Where is the `title` tag in your Layout view?

Comment: @TiesonT. I found this project in the Internet and downloaded it. Yes, you are right, it will use Orchard CMS. But I still do not know how to change page's title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not in the Layout.cshtml, but in the Document.cshtml. In there you will find somewhere at the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="@WorkContext.CurrentCulture">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow, archive" />

    <!-- See the construction of the title here -->
    <title>@Html.Title(title, siteName)</title>

    // other stuff
</head>
```

This file can be found in Orchard.Core/Shapes/Views/Document.cshtml

You probably do not want to change this in this document, because then you are changing core files (which is a bad practice, for example if you update Orchard the file will be overwritten again).

Luckily for you, Orchard is an amazing CMS that allows you to customize everything, without changing the core.

I suggest, if you haven't done that already, to create a new theme, based on the TheThemeMachine theme, copy the Document.cshtml to its views directory and change in it what you want.

[Here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme) you can find how to create a custom theme